# iptraf-ng error floating point exception

Tags: networking, monitoring

I installed iptraf-ng (v1.1.4) on ubuntu 18.04

```
sudo apt install iptraf-ng
```

But when I try to activate the "logging" option, iptraf freezes and the message comes out **Floating Point Exception** (in the image in Spanish **Excepción de coma flotante**)

[image]

[image]

**Additional information, apparently not related to the problem:**

iptraf-ng does not create the default folder for log, so I must create it manually

```
sudo mkdir /var/log/iptraf-ng
```

[image]

crash:

[image]

**Error research:**

I have researched and propose a patch call [0001-BUGFIX-fix-Floating-point-exception-in-tcplog_flowra.patch](https://github.com/pld-linux/iptraf-ng/blob/master/0001-BUGFIX-fix-Floating-point-exception-in-tcplog_flowra.patch) (which is only for compilations)

Does someone know how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

**Update:**

the issue is fixed in iptraf-ng 1.2.1 release

PD: this folder needs to be created manually for the `iface_stats_general.log` to be generated

```
sudo mkdir /var/log/iptraf-ng
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem but if you force Promiscuous mode it works.

Comment: No, actually, it doesnt always works fine. But with just one interface selected, i never had the bug until now.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Regarding your comment: I recommend that you **[edit]** your answer to explain any important limitations you've found that apply to it.

Comment: Does not work for me - Forced Promiscuous and only one interface seleted.

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 worked with iptraf-ng v1.1.4 and your answer is the solution. But, it is no longer necessary. In ubuntu 22.04 the iptraf-ng v1.2.1 bug was fixed

Answer (score 0):

Same issue. At first I noticed 'sudo apt install iptraf' leads to the package 'iptraf-ng'. Well after receiving the 'floating point exception error' I thought I should give 'lubuntu 16.04 LTS' a chance and it worked with 'iptraf' fine, but only if I choose the '/tmp' folder for storage!

Thought wrong I could do the same with my '18.04 LTS'.

Comment: It does not work. In any folder that you put the iptrafxxx.log the same error occurs (in Ubuntu 18.04.x 64)